# Ruby - Watir webdriver Timeout after browser.goto(url) even though URL is successfully loaded

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am first time user trying to run Cucumber tests in Ubuntu.
Note: all the tests have been tested successfully on windows machines.

```
ubuntu 12.04
Ruby 2.1.0
selenium-webdriver (2.40.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.8)
cucumber (1.3.10)
```

When i try running the same tests in Ubuntu, I get:

> Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in`rbuf_fill'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in`readline'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in`read_new'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1408:in `block in transport_request'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in`catch'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `transport_request'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1378:in`request'
>   /home/ivs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1371:in `block in request'

I can see that the Target page is loaded successfully but the test doesnt want to continue

I can see similar questions in 
[How to deal with a page which fails to load and continue testing in Watir-Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540268/how-to-deal-with-a-page-which-fails-to-load-and-continue-testing-in-watir-webdri)

[Watir/Selenium - browser.goto keep getting TimeOut error on Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319538/watir-selenium-browser-goto-keep-getting-timeout-error-on-chrome-and-firefox)

but both doesn't have proper resolution.

Can someone assist me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this actually related to your network issue. I think this issue was caused by failed to load all your web resources . selenium will wait for all the resouces to be loaded, if they can't be completed in a certain time, like 60 seconds, it will through out timeout exception.

Comment: Thanks for your input.. it did turn out to be network related.. even though they are all on the same subnet we were using a proxy to go out and comeback in which was causing this timeout...